# Show plots created by Matlab GUI in web browser

Tags: javascript, html, json, matlab, user-interface

I have a Matlab GUI (.exe) created with GUIDE, which evaluates measurements and show the results in plots which can be saved in several formats(svg, png, jpeg).

I want to display the plots in the web browser (e.g. Firefox), so save in a HTML file which I can run and see my plots. I must have the opportunity to zoom into the plots.

It is possible to create a server and communicate with JSON and plot then with Canvas or is there any other possibility? How can I communicate between HTML/JavaScript and my Matlab GUI to plot the graphs in the web browser?

Thank you very much!

Best regards 
Ralph

Comment: 'zoomable' means that you'll need a vector image (eps, pdf etc). Since MATLAB is proprietary, I doubt it'll run on websites. You're best off saving vector images and display those in a web browser, separated from MATLAB.

Comment: you can save your plots directly as [pdf](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/12854-print-a-figure-into-pdf) so they will be 'zoomable'

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But I want to zoom in the graphs without changing the location of the axis.. So the axis should be at the same place where they were